# concatenation with implode and quotes won't parse

Tags: php, implode

I am looping through a key,value array with multiple data types possible in the value and I need to convent it to a query string on a URL. This section is trying to take a key like "name:in" and an array like ("one","two","three") and come up with a string like 'name:in=("one","two","three")'

```
if((gettype($val) == 'array') {
     $retStr .= $key . '=("' . implode('","',$val) . '")'              
}
elseif...
```

and I'm getting this error:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'elseif' (T_ELSEIF) in
> C:\Users\JAMESB\Documents\webroot\BC\swamp\1.php on line 52

I've tried different combinations of apostrophes and quotes escaped and unescaped and I'm getting nowhere.

Thanks,

JimB

Comment: Are you just missing the `;` on the end of the line?

Comment: No, that changes the error to an unexpected ; error

Comment: It was the ()... I split an if(( ) || ( ))) into a an if ..elseif and didn't remove the outer ( ). A newbie error